# How can I show that $\{f\in C([0,1]): d(f,0)\leq 1\}$ is not compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

> Let me consider $C[0,1]$ with the metric $d(f,g)=\max\{|f(t)-g(t)|: t\in [0,1]\}$ and define $D=\{f\in C([0,1]): d(f,0)\leq 1\}$ I want to show that this is not compact.

I know that it is enough to show that it is not sequentially compact, therefore I thought that if I find a sequence in $D$ s.t. there exists no convergent subsequence I would be done right?

But if I take $f_n(x)=x^n$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ then clearly $f_n\in D$. But as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we know that $f_n\rightarrow 0$ if $x\in [0,1)$ and $f_n\rightarrow 1$ if $x=1$. But then the limit is discontinuous. But this would then show that there exists no convergent subsequence with limit in $D$

Is this correct?

Comment: Seems good to me.

Comment: @BrunoB okey thanks a lot!

Comment: Let $f_n(x)=\sin(\pi 2^nx).$ For $n>m$ and $x_m=2^{-m-1}$ we get $f_n(x_m)=0$ and $f_m(x_m)=1.$ Hence $\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty \ge 1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc sorry is this a further example or will you say that my "proof" is wrong?

Comment: Your proof is fine. Sorry for not mentioning that in my first comment. There is a general theorem, that the unit ball in any infinite dimensional  normed space  is not compact.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc ah perfect thanks a lot!

Comment: To me your proof is not completely satisfactory. When you write _“But then the limit is discontinuous”_, this function ($\chi_{\{1\}}$, the characteristic function of $\{1\}$) is not a limit according to $d$. (On the other hand it is indeed the limit of $(f_n)_n$ according to another topology, namely the product one on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$). This would need some clarification/development IMHO.